# What object type are multiple selected sheets in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, late-binding

Contrary to what I would think, multiple selected sheets are not a Worksheets object type.

After multi-selecting 2 or more sheets. The way I get the selection is as so:

```
var selection = ExcelApp.Selection; //Returns object type
```

I've tried getting the "Name" property to try and give me a hint by using late binding with:

```
string name = selection.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, selection, null).ToString();
```

But this throws errors for the given selection type.

Any ideas?

Comment: `selection.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, selection, null)` does not seem to make much sense as you cannot assume the object has a Name property. Why not use `selection.GetType().Name`?

Comment: selection.GetType().Name returns "_ComObject", so it's not very useful. I was only using the Name property as a shot in the dark to get the object type, as it works for most objects in Excel. I don't plan on actually using it in the code.

Comment: All right, got it. I came across an article describing how to test which interfaces are implemented by a COM object, but I guess Tim's answer hit the mark already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, `ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets` returns a `Sheets` collection, so I imagine it will be similar in C#

Yep:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.window.selectedsheets(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: + 1 :) Yep it is the same in C# as well :)