# How to programmatically group (shift select) sheets in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

This topic is related to: [What object type are multiple selected sheets in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591443/what-object-type-are-multiple-selected-sheets-in-excel#comment13757157_10591443)

To give an overview of the problem, I run some code that changes my selection in Excel, and I want to return the selection to what it originally was (I call this "originalSelection"). In most instances, you can just invoke the Select() method on the originalSelection.

```
var originalSelection = ExcelApp.Selection;
originalSelection.GetType().InvokeMember("Select", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, originalSelection , null);
```

With multiple sheets selected, the selection type is always of a range (it's what Excel defaults to). However, if you have multiple sheets selected, you can run into errors when trying to invoke Select again. You need to do some dancing around to get things to work.

If multiple sheets are selected, but not all the sheets, you can do the follow:

```
selectedSheets.Select();
activeSheet.Activate();
originalSelection.Select(); //this was casted to an Excel.Range
```

However, if all the sheets are selected, the `activeSheet.Activate()` line deselects all the other selected sheets. This also happens if you try it natively using the UI.

I was wondering if there is a way to pragmatically mimic shift-selecting sheets one by one through the code? Closest stuff I've found is stuff with range groupings, but nothing for sheets.

I tried to keep my overview brief, but if you need more clarification on what I'm doing, just ask.

Comment: Can't you just activate the sheet __before__ you select the group?

Comment: No, it changes the active sheet to the first sheet in the ordering (how convenient, right?). And also, if you follow up the Sheets.Select() with a range.Select() it will throw an error if that range isn't on that active sheet. That's why I do the active in between those calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out a way programatically select sheets.

You can create a string array of names, and use the ordering of the array to get a collection of the sheets. Select this collection, and you should have all the specified sheets selected.

```
String[] sheetsToBeSelected = {"Sheet3","Sheet1","Sheet2"}; //Note, Sheet3 is the first item in this array
excel.Workbook workbook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook; //get your Excel application however you want
excel.Sheets worksheets = workbook.Worksheets; //get all the sheets in this workbook

//This gets a collection of the sheets specified and ordered by the array of names passed in. 
//Just call select on this collection, and the first sheet in the collection becomes the active sheet!
((excel.Sheets)worksheets.get_Item(sheetsToBeSelected)).Select();
```