# Adding Footers to Excel Sheet Collections

Tags: c#, excel, footer, excel-interop

I am trying to add footers to sheets in an Excel Workbook as part of a C# program.  I am able to add them one tab at a time via the code below, but its very time consuming @ about a minute per workbook of about 10 tabs.

```
public void addFooter(Excel.Workbook wkbk)
    {
        string footer = "test footer";
            foreach (Excel.Worksheet wksht in wkbk.Worksheets)
            {
                if (chkRemoveCoverFooter.Checked == true && wksht.Name == "Cover" || wksht.Visible != Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    wksht.PageSetup.RightFooter = footer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have found that I can group the sheets via the question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622200/how-to-programmatically-group-shift-select-sheets-in-excel).
 I was able to get the group to select below, but I am stumped how I would access the PageSetup to change all the footers at once.  I know it can be easily done via VBA, but there is no "With" statement in C# to work with.  Thank you in advance for any pointers.

```
public void addFooter(Excel.Workbook wkbk)
    {
        string footer = "Test Footer";
        List<string> footerSheets = new List<string>();

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet wksht in wkbk.Worksheets)
        {
            if (chkRemoveCoverFooter.Checked == true && wksht.Name == "Cover" || wksht.Visible != Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                footerSheets.Add(wksht.Name);
            }
        }
        string[] footerSheetsArray = footerSheets.ToArray();
        ((Excel.Sheets)wkbk.Worksheets.get_Item(footerSheetsArray)).Select();

        //add 'footer' string to all the selected pages at once.                    
    }
```